# Trouble finding particular solution of non-homegenous recurrence equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence equation:

$$x_{k+2}−6x_{k+1}+9x_k=5^k+k$$

I found the homogeneous solution $x_h=c_13^k+c_2k3^k$ but I cannot find the particular solution $x_p$.

I know it should have the form $a5^k + bk$ or similar.

Could someone explain how to find the particular solution?

Comment: How far did you get in solving for the coefficients? You should have found that you also have to compensate constant terms, and indeed the ansatz for the $k·1^k$ term on the right side is $(bk+c)·1^k$, you always get the full polynomial of the given degree.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the RHS is $5^k+k$ and $5$ is not a root of $x^2-6x+9=0$ and so a particular solution can be written as
$$ x_k=a5^k+bk+c. $$
Putting it in the equation, you can easily get constants $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

As the recurrence is linear, we can use the $Z$ transform

$$
\cases{
Z[x_{k*2}-6x_{k+1}+9x_k]=(z-3)^2X[z]\\
Z[5^k+k] = \frac{z \left(z^2-z-4\right)}{(z-5) (z-1)^2}
}
$$

and then

$$
X[z] = \frac{z ((z-1) z-4)}{(z-5) \left(z^2-4 z+3\right)^2}
$$

after inversion we have a particular solution:

$$
x_p(k) = \frac{1}{12} \left(3 \left(5^k-2\cdot 3^k+1\right)-\left(3^k-3\right) k\right)
$$